# GLMER model produces different values for fitted.values() and predict() on same data

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm, lme4, mixed-models

I've trained a pretty complex (random intercept and slope) mixed logistic model which I'm then using to predict new data. My predictions were way off so I compared the predicted values for my original data and noticed that they are very different from my `fitted.values()`. E.g. taking just the first data point, the fitted value is 0.359, the predicted value (`predict(model, newdata=data, type="response"`) is 0.0585. I'm pretty sure the issue relates to the random effects, because if I predict the same data point with only fixed effects I get 0.707, which is what I'd expect, and random effects only gives 0.0252 which is very wrong.

You can see the different random effect groups by plotting fitted vs predicted (below) This also shows how the gradients within groups are the same so it looks like a problem with the intercepts rather than the slopes.

Any help would be really appreciated!

[image: Predicted vs Fitted Values]

EDIT: In case it helps, the formula basically looks like this:

```
y ~ (1 | re1) + 
    (1 | re2) + 
    (1 | re3) +  
    fe1 + fe2 + 
    (1 + rs1 |  re1) + 
    (1 + rs1 | re2) + 
    (1 |  re4:re1) + 
    (1 | re4:re2) + 
    (1 |  re5:re2) + 
    (1 | re5:re1) + 
    (1 +  rs2 | re1) + 
    (1 + rs2 |  re2) + 
    (1 + rs3 | re1) + 
    (1 +  rs3 | re2)
```

EDIT 2: Here is a reprex. I tried this with a few different seeds and the difference varies quite a lot. E.g. seed 42 looks almost identical (but the results are not quite the same).

```
library(lme4)

set.seed(25)

y <- as.factor(round(runif(1000,0,1)))

re1 <- as.factor(round(runif(1000,1,5)))
re2 <- as.factor(round(runif(1000,1,4)))
re3 <- as.factor(round(runif(1000,0,1)))

fe1 <- runif(1000,0,1)
fe2 <- runif(1000,0,1)

rs1 <- runif(1000,0,1)
rs2 <- runif(1000,0,1)

df <- data.frame(y=y,
                 re1=re1,
                 re2=re2,
                 re3=re3,
                 fe1=fe1,
                 fe2=fe2,
                 rs1=rs1,
                 rs2=rs2)

model <- glmer(y ~ (1 | re1) + 
                 (1 | re2) + 
                 (1 | re3) +  
                 fe1 + fe2 + 
                 (1 + rs1 |  re1) + 
                 (1 + rs1 | re2), family="binomial", data=df)

plot(fitted.values(model), predict(model, newdata=df, type="response"))
```

Comment: I don't think this can possibly be answered without a [mcve]. Your model looks a bit strange (*lots* of random effects (how big is your data set?), and the intercept variation across groups `re1`, `re2`, `re3` is included in many of your components). I would probably suggest `y ~ fe1 + fe2 + (1 + rs1 + rs2 + rs3 || re1) + (1 + rs1 + rs2 + rs3 || re2) + ...`

Comment: Thank you @BenBolker, I've added a minimum reproducible example. My sample size is N=21,197 but I don't have a great sense of how many random effects a model with that sample size can sustain, is there a rule of thumb? That formula looks much better, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model:

```
glmer(y ~ (1 | re1) + 
                   (1 | re2) + 
                   (1 | re3) +  
                   fe1 + fe2 + 
                   (1 + rs1 |  re1) + 
                   (1 + rs1 | re2), family="binomial", data=df)
```

is pathological. `(1 | re1)`  and `(1 | re2)` are redundant since you also fit `(1 + rs1 |  re1)` and `(1 + rs1 | re2)`. If the intention was to estimate  uncorrelated random effects then you can do so using `(1 | re1) + (0 + rs1 | re1)` and `(1 | re2) + (0 + rs1 | re2)`

If you remove these redundant terms:

```
  model <- glmer(y ~ (1 | re3) +  
                   fe1 + fe2 + 
                   (1 + rs1 |  re1) + 
                   (1 + rs1 | re2), family="binomial", data=df)
```

then you obtain the same values from `fitted.values` and `predict`:

```
plot(fitted.values(model), predict(model, newdata=df, type="response"))
```

[image]

This model is singular - and so is the original one - but that is a different problem.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I'll give this a go on my data. Do you know why it being pathological might cause the difference between prediction and fitted values?

Comment: You're welcome :) I shouldn't worry too much about what happens in pathological models. I would be more concerned with the singularity. Also, when you fit random slopes for `rs1` but you don't include `rs1` as a fixed effect then you are forcing the overall "effect" of `rs1` to be zero, which in most situations is not what you want.